# Can't use inheritors for type argument of type argument of method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have

```
public abstract class RadioButtonGroup<LayoutT> : where LayoutT: LayoutGroup
```

and it's inheritor

```
public class RadioButtonGroupVertical : RadioButtonGroup<VerticalLayoutGroup>
```

`Note: VerticalLayoutGroup is inheritor of LayoutGroup.`

Then I define builder function

```
static T CreateRadioButtonGroup<T>() where T: RadioButtonGroup<LayoutGroup>
```

And want to use it like

```
RadioButtonGroupVertical radioButtonGroup = UIToolsBuilder.CreateRadioButtonGroup<RadioButtonGroupVertical>();
```

but I can't compiled it because compiler thinks that `RadioButtonGroupVertical` is not convertible to `RadioButtonGroup<LayoutGroup>`

I can add second type parameter to the method

```
public static T CreateRadioButtonGroup<T, TLayout>() where T: RadioButtonGroup<TLayout> where TLayout: LayoutGroup
```

but this way I need to always give it second type parameter of layout type which i don't want to give.

Comment: A `RadioButtonGroup<VerticalLayoutGroup>` is *not* a type derived from `RadioButtonGroup<LayoutGroup>`. That such a relationship exists between the type parameters does *not* make it true of the generic parameterized by those parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base non-generic abstract class:

`public abstract class RadioButtonGroup{}`

And then define the rest of the class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class RadioButtonGroup<LayoutT> : RadioButtonGroup where LayoutT: LayoutGroup {}

public class UIBuilder
{
   public static RadioButtonGroup CreateRadioButtonGroup(){...}
   public static RadioButtonGroup<T> CreateRadioButtonGroup<T>() {...}
}
```

And you can create wither